# Can't change settings on Putty configuration section ("Open" instead of "Save")

Tags: windows-10, putty

I use Win10 Home insider preview. No problems with the OS.

In Putty I go to configuration to change in *appearance* and *colours* a bit.

When I do the desired change and click on "Open" (seems to be the default button for "Save"), nothing happens.

[image]

This is true to all tabs I checked.

- Tried to update to a newer version. Didn't help.

Comment: *Can't change nothing*, so you can change everything? The 'save' button for PuTTY is on the Session tab. Select the default entry and click save.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as the OP. Open button does nothing, no matter the context, no way to exit the config except "cancel", which results in no changes being saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either change preferences for a specific session, or in a global way.

To change the default (global) preferences for all connections, go to the "Session" category, pick the "Default" Settings from the Saved Sessions list, hit "Save", and then do the preference changes.

To change for a specific session, go to the Sessions category, fill in details under 'Saved Sessions', hit "Save", and then do the preference changes.